# Python Parallel SSH - Netmiko/Napalm - Cisco SMB switches stuck at sending command

Tags: python-3.x, cisco-ios, netmiko, parallel-ssh, napalm

I am trying to determine vendor + version (using python NAPALM and parallel-ssh) of network switches (Huawei VRP5/8, Cisco Catalyst and Cisco SMB (SF/SG):

```
admin@server:~$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from napalm import get_network_driver
>>> driver = get_network_driver('ios')
>>> device = driver('ip', 'username', 'password')
>>> device.open()
>>> print(device.get_facts())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/altepro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/napalm/ios/ios.py", line 811, in get_facts
    show_ver = self._send_command('show version')
  File "/home/altepro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/napalm/ios/ios.py", line 165, in _send_command
    output = self.device.send_command(command)
  File "/home/altepro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/utilities.py", line 600, in wrapper_decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/altepro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1694, in send_command
    raise ReadTimeout(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
Pattern not detected: '\x1b\\[Ksg300\\-ab\\-1\\#' in output.

Things you might try to fix this:
1. Explicitly set your pattern using the expect_string argument.
2. Increase the read_timeout to a larger value.
```

Where **sg300-ab-1** is sysname of the switch (Cisco SMB - sg300 in this case, but i have tested this on several versions and types of the SMB lineup)

Things that i have tried:
Tried several version of netmiko, napalm (And its drivers including ios-350) and parallel-ssh. Tried several fresh linux servers with fresh install of napalm and parallel-ssh.

SSH is tested using the same server and credentials and it works without any problems.

When i use parallel-ssh the device doesnt even raise exception or timeout - it just goes stuck in the command:

**output = client.run_command(cmd)**

```
hosts = ['192.168.1.50']
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='my_user', password='my_pass')
cmd = 'show version'

output = client.run_command(cmd)
for host_out in output:
    for line in host_out.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Thanks for any kind of help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the prompt isn't getting recognized properly.  I'm not very familiar with either ParallelSSHClient or napalm, but I have worked with netmiko and that looks like where the error is.  Here's some steps that can possible get you closer to figuring out what's happening.  I suspect it's the prompt not being read correctly from the device.

Set up debugging and a netmiko session and run a simple command

```
import logging
import netmiko
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

session = netmiko.ConnectHandler(
    host='192.168.1.50', 
    username='my_user', 
    password='my_pass', 
    device_type='cisco_ios')

results = session.send_command('show version')
```

If this fails with the same error, then it's the prompt (possibly the \x1b escape character).  Try again but with a simpler expect_string, like what's expected at the end of the prompt:

```
session.send_command('show version', expect_string="#")
```

If this gets you a result, then it's something about the how the prompt is being set for this device.

To see what's being found for the prompt:

```
session.find_prompt()
```

Edit:

Based on what you're reporting, the issue seems to be with the control code `\x1b\[` being included in the prompt.  It's possible this can be disabled on the device itself, but I'm unfamiliar with that platform.  The napalm API doesn't expose netmiko's send_command method.  It should still be fixable.  This solution would be a hack to make things work, nothing that I'd recommend relying on.

Establish a class that will act as your fix.  This will be instantiated with the netmiko session (`device.device`) and will be used to replace the `send_command` method.

```
class HackyFix:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
        self.original_send_command = session.send_command

    def send_command(self, command):
        original_prompt = self.session.find_prompt()
        fixed_prompt = original_prompt.replace(r"\x1b[", "")
        print(
            f"send_command intercepted. {original_prompt} replaced with {fixed_prompt}"
        )
        return self.original_send_command(command, expect_string=fixed_prompt)
```

Then in your existing napalm code, add this right after `device.open()`:

```
hackyfix = HackyFix(device.device)
device.device.send_command = hackyfix.send_command
```

Now all of napalm's calls to `send_command` will go through your custom fix that will find the prompt and modify it before passing it to `expect_string`.

Last edit.

It's an [ANSI Escape Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that's being thrown in by the SG300.  Specifically it's the one that [clears from cursor to end of line](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797?permalink_comment_id=3948619#gistcomment-3948619).  It's also a [known issue](https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/index.html#netmiko.BaseConnection.strip_ansi_escape_codes) with the SG300.  The good news is that someone made a napalm [driver](https://github.com/napalm-automation-community/napalm-s350) to support it.  One big difference between the SG300 driver and the IOS driver is the netmiko device_type is `cisco_s300`.  When this device_type is used, `strip_ansi_escape_codes` is ran against the output.

Behavior of that escape code tested in bash:

```
$ printf "This gets cleared\r"; code="\x1b[K"; printf "${code}This is what you see\n"
This is what you see
```

You can validate that setting `cisco_s300` as the device_type fixes the issue:

```
session = netmiko.ConnectHandler(
    host='192.168.1.50', 
    username='my_user', 
    password='my_pass', 
    device_type='cisco_s300')

results = session.send_command('show version')
```

This should give a result with no modification to the `expect_string` value.  If that works and you're looking to get results sooner or later, the following is a better fix than the hacky fix above.

```
from napalm.ios import IOSDriver

class QuickCiscoSG300Driver(IOSDriver):
    def __init__(self, hostname, username, password, timeout=60, optional_args=None):
        super().__init__(hostname, username, password, timeout, optional_args)

    def open(self):
        device_type = "cisco_s300"
        self.device = self._netmiko_open(
            device_type, netmiko_optional_args=self.netmiko_optional_args
        )


device = QuickCiscoSG300Driver("192.168.1.50", "my_user", "my_pass")
device.open()
device.get_facts()
```

Or you can get the [driver](https://github.com/napalm-automation-community/napalm-s350) (better option, unless this happens to be the driver you already tried)

Comment: Seems to be working - it returns the command output with the expect_string="#" ! now how to specify it trough parallel-ssh and napalm :D

Thanks for help !

Comment: It is, BUT it raises exception after printing100+ lines "DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:", then it says: OSError: Search pattern never detected in send_command: [Ksg300\-ab\-1\#

Comment: When you use napalm, after `device.open()` what happens when you try `device.device.send_command('show version')` vs `device.device.send_command('show version', expect_string='#')`?  Also what is the output of `device.device.find_prompt()` ?

Comment: That Works !
>>> print(device.device.send_command("show version", expect_string='#'))
```Active-image: flash://system/images/image1.bin
  Version: 2.4.0.94
  MD5 Digest: 6f5be217100f34929986f2e93dd2d5e9
  Date: 31-May-2018
  Time: 02:39:58
  Inactive after reboot
sg300-ab-1#
```

find_prompt() output:

```
>>> device.device.find_prompt()
'\x1b[Ksg300-ab-1#'
```

It seems to be working like this, but when i try any method from napalm (get_facts() for example):

napalm.base.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Search pattern never detected in send_command: [Ksg300\-ab\-1\#

Comment: See edit.  That device is adding the control codes to the prompt which is messing things up.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and fix! But the main thing why i wanted to fix this issue was to use parallel-ssh to check all devices on the network (send 2 commands - show version and display version) to determine which driver to use when connecting with napalm. (The script will not have any idea what the box is) The runtime should be - parallel-ssh to check the version and vendor and then napalm connection with premade functions using the right driver for the device (Including all napalm drivers, sg300 included). Any thoughts for this kind of implementation ?

Comment: A separate question focusing on parallel-ssh might help, focusing specifically on the presence of `\x1b[K` in the SG100's output.  You can also bring it up as an issue on their repo, as it looks like they're keeping it up to date.   Separate from that, the best I can suggest is to combine the built in `concurrent.futures` with netmiko's `ssh_autodetect` library.  `ssh_autodetect` can serve as a standin for the manual `show ver` processing.  Even if `ssh_autodetect` doesn't work out for you, `concurrent.futures` is the way to go for concurrency when async doesn't work out.

Comment: Sweet, thank you so much for your time ! You have helped me a lot, clear explanation and a fix with many good advices. Thanks again !